# How to push each object value into array from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON response with key-values like:

```
....
    "usp-custom-90":"45.45257926613316,9.178168599999935"
....
```

Note `usp-custom-90`has dash!

I need something like (fields doens't exist, it's just an example):

```
            data.forEach(({fields})=>{
              coordsB.push(
                ...fields['usp-custom-90']
              );
            });
```

Where coordsB is an array defined before.

The json would be:

```
],
      "usp-custom-90":"45.47841306255037,9.120865849999973",
      "_links":{  
         "self":[  
            {  
               "href":"https:\/\/www.example.it\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/128402"
            }
         ],
         "collection":[  
            {  
               "href":"https:\/\/www.example.it\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
            }
         ],
         "about":[
```

I need to push the value of each `"usp-custom-90"`

Full code (wrong as it is using fields which doesn't exist):

```
    fetch('https://www.example.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>{
        var coordsB = [];
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(({fields})=>{
          coordsB.push(
            ...fields['usp-custom-90']
          );
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the real response?

Comment: @Ele the json there is really, there just would be many usp-custom-90

Comment: Please, post the exact response structure.

Comment: how about something like `obj.map(x=> x["usp-custom-90"])`, where obj is your json object?

Comment: shouldn't we use .flat when using map? But it isn't cross browser @David784

Comment: @David784 also I need to push each of them

Comment: My `map` suggestion returns an array of 26 entries. I checked, and that's all the instances in the pastebin sample you linked. So...nope, I'm pretty sure the `map` is all you need, unless the data structure can vary.

Comment: @David784 ok thanks, so based on the full code updated in the quetsion, how would I use that to push the values in the array?

Comment: `var coordsB = data.map(x=> x["usp-custom-90"])` should do the trick. No need to push, `map` will create the array for you.

Comment: @David784 ok perfect, put that into an answer pls, works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [data sample](https://pastebin.com/raw/EfHtZ0Zv) linked in the comments, the structure is an array of objects, each object containing a `usp-custom-90` property. This is a perfect situation for the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operator for arrays.

So in the above code, this one line will do it all for you. It will create the array and populate it with all the values you're looking for.

```
var coordsB = data.map(x=> x["usp-custom-90"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines would do I guess.

```
Object.entries(object).reduce((ac,[k,v],i,a)=>(ac.push(v['usp-custom-90']),ac),[])
```

Looks like from your paste bin main object is an array with objects inside which have the key you want then:

```
YourMainArray.reduce((ac,d,i,a)=>(ac.push(d['usp-custom-90']),ac),[])
```

Tested it, gives you this:

```
["45.45257926613316,9.178168599999935", "45.47841306255037,9.120865849999973", "9.924,-84.090", "44.948,9.039", "45.464150416139695,9.1906395499999", "45.651,11.303", "43.83734441524854,7.905822499999999", "45.05926341591318,9.3354875", "44.872988115810074,13.85009094999998", "44.97805886586813,8.895478499999967", "45.472119466144186,9.173527250000006", "45.165,9.183", "41.937,12.441", "45.464993216140186,9.147909499999969", "45.48624411615216,9.16677489999995", "45.209,9.147", "45.464993216140186,9.147909499999969", "41.848264464222716,12.665936949999946", "45.464993216140186,9.147909499999969", "45.46851557705748,9.139416449999999", "44.507,11.314", "36.731,14.873", "36.222,-121.759", "10.093,77.060", "45.454327616134165,9.175796900000023", "45.469282816142574,9.176045000000045"]
```

Comment: how would I put this into my code tho? See updated question with full code

Comment: if you pasted an example data with entire 'fields' open I could have said that to you. The object inside Object.entries is your entire object with whatever 'fields' is. Within each MainObject['someKey'] there is an another object with your usp-custom. Isnt this what you want?

Comment: Ok test the above